# PHP function execution time taking long

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp

I have a good written function; I guess, but when I use this function on a client that has many transactions it takes like 20 seconds, increasing everytime I add new transaction. This functions starts recounting all client debts since the beginning.
I am using :

- WAMP SERVER 3.1.4
- PHP 7.2.10
- MYSQL 5.7.23

I have tried some changes in php.ini

**php.ini**

```
post_max_size = 256M
upload_max_filesize = 128M
memory_limit = 1G
max_input_vars = 10000
```

and

**my.ini**

```
key_buffer_size = 256M
max_allowed_packet = 128M
sort_buffer_size = 128M
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 128M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 128M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 512M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 512M
[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 512M
[isamchk]
key_buffer_size = 512M
sort_buffer_size = 128M
read_buffer_size = 256M
write_buffer_size = 256M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 512M
sort_buffer_size_size = 512M
read_buffer_size = 256M
write_buffer_size = 256M
```

**and here's the function**

```
function reCalculateAll($conn, $clid, $cltp){
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE client_id = ? AND client_type = ? ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(transaction_date, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') ASC");
        $stmt->bind_param('is', $clid, $cltp);
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->fetch();
        $numberofrows = $stmt->num_rows;
        while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
            $r = getAllTransactionsClient($conn, $clid, $cltp);
            $result = array();
            foreach($r as $i => $p){
                $result[$p['client_type'].$p['client_id']][] = $p;
                foreach ($result as $rr){
                    foreach ($rr as $c => $k){
                        reset($rr);
                        $trid = $k['id'];
                        $trcn = $k['client_id'];
                        $trtp = $k['client_type'];
                        $trdt = $k['transaction_date'];
                        if($c === key($rr)){
                            // FIX TRANSACTION
                            $addm = 0;
                            $stmtf = $conn->prepare("UPDATE transactions SET client_oldfunds = ?, client_newfunds = ? + added_amount where id = ?");
                            $stmtf->bind_param('ssi', $addm, $addm, $trid);
                            $stmtf->execute();
                            $stmtf->close();
                            $addm = $k['client_newfunds'];
                            } else {
                            $stmtn = $conn->prepare("UPDATE transactions SET client_oldfunds = ?, client_newfunds = ? + added_amount where id = ?");
                            $stmtn->bind_param('ssi', $addm, $addm, $trid);
                            $stmtn->execute();
                            $stmtn->close();
                            $addm = $k['client_newfunds'];
                        }                               
                            $cnf = getLastDebtFromTransaction($conn, $trtp, $trcn);
                            setDebts($conn, $trtp, $cnf, $trcn);
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        $results->free();
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $numberofrows = $stmt->num_rows;
        if($numberofrows == 0){
            setDebts($conn, $cltp, '0', $clid);
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
```

getAllTransactionsClient Function

```
    function getAllTransactionsClient($conn, $clid, $cltp){
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE client_id = ? AND client_type = ? ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(transaction_date, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') ASC");
        $stmt->bind_param('is', $clid, $cltp);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $products = array();
        
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $products[] = $row;
        }
        return $products;
        $stmt->close();
    }
```

Comment: Do you mind telling us some metrics? How many transactions are we talking about? How many update-queries are being executed?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson what kind of metrics ? do you mean data ?

Comment: edit question to include `SHOW CREATE transactions` output. How big is the table. Doing updates in a loop isn't something that is database friendly. SQL servers do loops well so you don't need to.  reCalculateAll should be a single SQL statement. Statement prep should go outside the loop. Welcome to SO

Comment: By metrics I mean numbers. If your select query returns 2 transactions to iterate through, then 20 seconds is a lot. If your select query returns 1.000.000 transactions, then 20 seconds is pretty fast (since you update them in a loop).

Comment: @danblack thank you for taking time to read my question, and answering it, I will try to find a way to replace this multiple loops but I created this code under pressure and in no time just to fix a problem with my software, still looking for better ideas

Comment: @MagnusEriksson there are like 40 transactions, but they are increasing

Comment: What does the `getAllTransactionsClient` do? You call the routine in a loop while passing the same parameters every time. You also pass the `$conn` while you still have the rows from the first query in the buffer.

Comment: @slaakso, check my question again, I have added that function to the end

Comment: So you are repeating the same query in a loop that started the loop with? That does not make sense. Then you have calls to `getLastDebtFromTransaction` and `setDebts` in the loop that probably do similar things and yet again, you are passing in the same `$conn` while the main query is still in progress. Maybe just rewrite the whole function as one query or a stored procedure call.

Comment: Can you explain what your code is supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code needs improving, I see that there are multiple loops in one,
Here's your first function, you can get rid of the last one because it is kinda useless.

**Actual function should be like this:**

```
    function reCalculateAll($conn, $client_id, $client_type){
        // THE FOLLOWING QUERY WILL REPLACE this function for you getAllTransactionsClient();
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, added_amount FROM transactions WHERE client_id = ? AND client_type = ? ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(transaction_date, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') ASC");
        $stmt -> bind_param("is", $client_id, $client_type);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> store_result();
        $stmt -> bind_result($transaction_id, $added_amount);
        // THIS $oldfunds stands for your old $addm
        $oldfunds = 0;
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            $newfunds = $oldfunds + $added_amount;
            $stmtd = $conn->prepare("UPDATE transactions SET client_oldfunds = ?, client_newfunds = ? WHERE id = ?");
            $stmtd->bind_param("ssi", $oldfunds, $newfunds, $transaction_id);
            $stmtd->execute();
            $oldfunds = $newfunds;
        }
        $stmt->close();
        // this should send 0 if there is no transactions
        setDebts($conn, $client_type, $oldfunds, $client_id);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Pre-cursor**

I'm going to skip over "answering your question" - I think a lot of the problems are highlighted in the comments above - and move straight in to a solution for what I think you intend your code to do...

## The Problem

Your code isn't easy to follow, however, I believe the gist of the issue is that:

1. Your database has been corrupted in some way and fields `client_oldfunds` and `client_newfunds` no longer hold the correct data.
2. You trust the field `added_amount` is correct and want to go back and recalculate the fields above for each transaction so that it all tallies up?

### Database

**Table Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
    id bigint AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    client_id bigint,
    client_type varchar(20),
    client_oldfunds decimal(10,2),
    client_newfunds decimal(10,2),
    added_amount decimal(10,2),
    transaction_date varchar(20)
);
```

**Example Current Data**

Assume that the transactions here are ordered by date.

```
id  | client_id   | client_type   | client_oldfunds   | client_newfunds   | added_amount
--- | ----------- | ------------- | ----------------- | ----------------- | --------------
1   | 1           | type_a        | 12.10             | 1.36              | 3.12
2   | 1           | type_a        | 6.00              | 432.42            | 4.50
3   | 1           | type_a        | 30.12             | 1.33              | 100.22
4   | 1           | type_a        | 23.1              | 1.22              | 10.2
5   | 1           | type_a        | 123.4             | 55.54             | 12.6
```

**Example Correct Data**

Assume that the transactions here are ordered by date.

```
id  | client_id   | client_type   | client_oldfunds   | client_newfunds   | added_amount
--- | ----------- | ------------- | ----------------- | ----------------- | --------------
1   | 1           | type_a        | 0                 | 3.12              | 3.12
2   | 1           | type_a        | 3.12              | 7.62              | 4.50
3   | 1           | type_a        | 7.62              | 107.84            | 100.22
4   | 1           | type_a        | 107.84            | 118.04            | 10.2
5   | 1           | type_a        | 118.04            | 130.64            | 12.6
```

### Code

**What we want it to do**

```
reCalculateAll{
   0 > Initialise a balance of 0
   1 > SELECT id and amount_added for all related transactions, in order
   2 > UPDATE the client_oldfunds to the balance and client_newfunds to the balance + the added_amount
   3 > UPDATE the balance to the new value (balance + added_amount)
}
```

**Actual Code**

```
function reCalculateAll($mysqli, $client_id, $client_type){
    $select_sql = "
        SELECT id, added_amount
        FROM transactions
        WHERE client_id = ?
            AND client_type = ?
        ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(transaction_date, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') ASC
    ";

    $select_query = $mysqli->prepare($select_sql);
    $select_query->bind_param("is", $client_id, $client_type);
    $select_query->execute();
    $select_query->store_result();
    $select_query->bind_result($transaction_id, $added_amount);

    $old_balance = 0;
    
    while($select_query->fetch()){
        $new_balance = $old_balance + $added_amount;

        $update_sql  = "
            UPDATE transactions
            SET client_oldfunds = ?,
                client_newfunds = ?
            WHERE id = ?
        ";

        $update_query = $mysqli->prepare($update_sql);
        $update_query->bind_param("ssi", $old_balance, $new_balance, $transaction_id);
        $update_query->execute();

        $old_balance = $new_balance;
    }
}
```

**N.B.**

You really should be storing your dates in the MySQL format "Y-m-d H:i:s". It makes sorting easier; formatting should happen when the date is output to the browser.